# Is object X *like* object Y if X=Y?

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions, logic

Imagine we have two names, X and Y, which describe the same object.

If X and Y are identical in every possible way, and therefore X=Y, is

> *X is like Y*.

a true statement?

Comment: It is not false, but you aready said they are the same, not *similar*, which is what "is like" means.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If X is *red* and Y is *round*, we can say that they both describe aspects of a red ball, but they won't be equal to each other. And to say that something is like itself would be bizarre. I am not *like* myself, I ***am*** myself.

Comment: Your question would benefit from concrete examples, rather than this abstract consideration.

Comment: @JasonBassford X and Y are not properties, they are names/labels. For example, X = "human" and Y = "person".

Comment: @KirkWoll See my last comment.

Comment: @MicahWindsor *Human* and *person* do not equal each other. Moreover, as a description of something, they *are* properties. On the other hand, *Bill* and *William* are names, and they can be names for the same thing. However, again, they do not equal each other.

Comment: @JasonBassford  *Human: n. A person.* Straight from Google. Just like the meaning of Bill is the meaning of William. Bill is a person whose birth name is William, and William is a person whose birth name is William. They are identical. Moreover, I stated that X and Y describe the same object for the purposes of this question, so we are not dealing with two separate people known as Bill and William. Bill and William are one!

Comment: @MicahWindsor Common nouns are not names, only proper nouns are names. The definition you give is for a common noun. But, regardless, while two words can refer to the same single thing, there is still only one thing. One thing cannot be identical to (or like) itself. In order to use *identical* or *like*, there has to be a plurality of things *described*, not a plurality of descriptions for a single thing.

Comment: @JasonBassford Obviously they're not names of people, they're names of things. But I think you know what I mean. And do you mean to tell me that The Rock is not identical to John Cena? Or that Marshall Mathers is not identical to Eminem?

Comment: @MicahWindsor There is only a single individual referred to by those names. That individual is *not* identical to himself. I think there is a category confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is identical (X==Y) then it is necessarily alike (but more than that)
If something is alike, it is not necessarily identical.

X equals / is identical to Y is thus a stronger / stricter statement (than alike)

So, as Weather Vane said in his comment, "X and Y are alike" is not a false statement, but it is one you would not say, as you already said (or if you haven't, you should say [because it provides more information]) that "X and Y are identical".

Saying "X is like Y" after saying they are identical actually takes away from the strength of the identical statement (and is confusing because why would you partially/potentially negate what you just said).